# meaning of enqueue_wakeup macro linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am not sure what is the meaning of the macro `ENQUEUE_WAKEUP` in linux mean. I have an intuition that it means to enqueue a task after it has woke up but still want to be sure.

The macro definition is:

`#define ENQUEUE_WAKEUP          1`

Note: For reference purposes in v3.5.4 it is defined in `/include/linux/sched.h` and referenced at many place but one such place I am having problem is function `enqueue_task_rt` in file `./kernel/sched/rt.c`

Comment: Did you look at the definition of the macro?  If your question is about its semantics, why didn't you include its definition in the question?

Comment: I did nit include it because I thought it was not relevant. But since you say, I have edited the question

Comment: and where the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is were it was introduced.

sched: Add enqueue/dequeue flags

In order to reduce the dependency on TASK_WAKING rework the enqueue
interface to support a proper flags field.

ENQUEUE_WAKEUP - the enqueue is a wakeup of a sleeping task

http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1004.0/00744.html